# How to use DateTime without using RE?

Tags: python-2.7

How to use this same logic without using the re.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Import the regular expression
import re

print "The task Begins"

print " The Begin time is at 03:00:00"
#Set the beginning time and name it as starttime
starttime="03:00:00"

print "The End time is at 03:59:59"
#Set the ending time and name it as endtime
endtime="03:59:59"

#Specify the time format
time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

#Using the condition
with open("abc.log", "r") as fh:

for line in fh.readlines():
    match = time_re.search(line)
    if match:
       matchDate = match.group(1)
       if matchDate >= starttime and matchDate <= endtime:
           print match.string.strip()

 print "The task is completed"
```

PS: Use the DateTime and Time .

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the current approach?

Comment: we don't write programs for you... what is the problem? are you a beginner in coding?

Comment: Yes man. I want to use datetime format. I used regular expression. I am a fresher man. Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.find() but it is better to use regular expression.

Comment: Aye Mate. I know, but the requirement is to use datetime

Comment: You are reading .log file and getting result by comparing startTime and endTime. Your question is not clear. Can you tell your exact problem for datetime. DateTime is for manipulating dates and times and Re is for matching operations.

Comment: Start and end time is the parameter value I set to get the log entry from log file. Suppose I have the logfile right, I want to find the log entry between the start time and end time. I don't know how to explain it better. Please understand.

Answer (score 0):

## Import the datetime

from datetime import datetime
import re

## Create two datetime object for 12:00:00 and 04:59:59 as dt1 and dt2 respectively

dt1 = datetime.strptime("12:00:00","%H:%M:%S").time()
dt2 = datetime.strptime("04:59:59","%H:%M:%S").time()

time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

for line in open("test.log", "r"):
        match = time_re.search(line)
        if match:
            matchdate = match.group(1)
            dt_match = datetime.strptime( matchdate, '%H:%M:%S').time()
            if dt_match >= dt1 and dt_match <= dt2:
                print match.string.strip()

Comment: Is this supposed to be a self-answer? Please correct your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.datetime.now()strftime("%d-%m-%Y")` to get date-month-year format if it will help you but I don't understand what you are trying to do because what you are currently doing is perfectly fine.